# Where-Object in Computed Expression in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm importing a CSV in PowerShell using `Import-Csv`.  The main processing is running a `Split()` method on a colum that contains firstname & lastname all together.  I'm then creating 2 new columns `Firstname` and `Lastname` using the split strings.

I'm trying to do something clever with the strings.  Some names that appear to be lastnames are actually firstnames, I can tell as they contain a hyphen.

My script is here:

```
function UpdateCSV {
    Param ($card) 

    $card
    #Import the CSV
    $kbc = Import-Csv $card
    #Split the Name to new fields Firstname & Lastname
    $kbc = $kbc | Select-Object -Property *, @{label='Lastname'; expression={$_.name.Split(' ')[0] | Where-Object {$_.name.Split(' ')[0] -contains "kim"}}}

    $kbc = $kbc | Select-Object -Property *, @{label='Firstname'; expression={$_.name.Split(' ')[1..1000]}}

    $kbc | Export-Csv -Path $card -NoTypeInformation
}

Set-Location "c:\scripts\CSVs"
$GetFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\scripts\CSVs -Recurse |
            where {$_.Extension -eq ".csv"}
foreach ($card in $GetFiles) {
    UpdateCSV $card
}
```

This line of code isn't working:

```
$kbc = $kbc | Select-Object -Property *, @{label='Lastname'; expression={$_.name.Split(' ')[0] | Where-Object {$_.name.Split(' ')[0] -contains "kim"}}}
```

But to prove the syntax of my `Where-Object` is working I've written this snippet that is working and it is returning data and they seem identical:

```
    $csv = Import-Csv c:\scripts\CSVs\kk.csv
    foreach ($c in $csv) {
        $frag = $c.name.Split(' ')
        $frag[1..10] | Where-Object {
            $frag[1..10] -match "kim"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How *exactly* is the line of code "not working"? What is the desired result? What is the actual result? Please provide sample input that would allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've looked at this for a whole 10 seconds, so it's possible I may get this wrong. I suspect, however, that the contains operator doesn't do what you think it does. Read this, https://devops-collective-inc.gitbooks.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-gotchas/content/manuscript/contains-isnt-like.html (even if it turns out that isn't the problem). Also, this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1.